# Possible to add current date to rsync working path?

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I have an every-hour rsync cron task that is used to add new files to the backup server. Directory structure is the following: `/myfiles/year/month/date` where year, month and date are actual dates of files. Cron task is defined as the file in the `/etc/cron.d`

The problem is that I have to indicate a "root" `/myfiles` directory to make rsync replicate my folder structure in the backup location with every new day. Amount of files is substantial - up to 1000 files a day, so rsync needs to iterate through all yearly files to build a copy list while it's not needed at all because I need to copy today's only files. As of April, it takes ~25 minutes even with `--ignore-existing` option.

Can someone help me to create a script or whatever to add a current year, month and date to the working rsync path in the cron task, if possible? The final result should look like that:

```
0 * * * *  root rsync -rt --ignore-existing /myfiles/2020/04/26 user@myserver:/myfiles/2020/04/26
```

where `/2020/04/26` is variable part that is changing every day.

I have very limited experience with *nix systems so I feel that is possible but basically have no clue how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an actual date to the path one can use the `date` utility or the builtin `printf` from the bash shell.

Using `date`

```
echo "/myfiles/$(date +%Y/%m/%d)"
```

Using `printf`

```
echo "/myfiles/$(printf '%(%Y/%m/%d)T')"
```

In your case when using the builtin `printf` you need to define the shell as `bash` in the cron entry.

```
0 * * * *  root rsync -rt --ignore-existing "/myfiles/$(printf '\%(\%Y/\%m/\%d)T')" "user@myserver:/myfiles/$(printf '\%(\%Y/\%m/\%d)T')"
```

Using `date` either define the `PATH` to include where the `date` utility is or just use an absolute path

```
0 * * * *  root rsync -rt --ignore-existing "/myfiles/$(/bin/date +\%Y/\%m/\%d)" "user@myserver:/myfiles/$(/bin/date +\%Y/\%m/\%d)"
```

- The `date` syntax should work on both GNU and BSD date.
- The `%` needs to be escaped inside the cron entry.
- See the local documentation on your `cron(5)` on how to add the PATH and SHELL variables. Although the SHELL normally can be `SHELL=/bin/bash` and PATH to `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks! To keep things simpler I just used absolute path for `date` as you advised. Especially thanks for escaping % within cron, I would be catching it for ever